# Google Admin SDK : Reports API Activities : Watch > Sends a tones of same notification

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-audit-api

I have created a Gsuite channel as per this reference https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/watch and its working fine. I can receive the webhooks for all the admin activities.

The problem is sometimes event such as **"ADD_GROUP_MEMBER"** or **"REMOVE_GROUP_MEMBER"** getting 10 to 12 times for the same user email and group email. I am also sending the response 200 for each webhooks but still, Gsuite keeps sending me the same events.

You can check on the attached events. I have received one webhook at 19:17:24 with some group member change. After 54 seconds I have again received the same event with all the same data. This happens almost 12 times. It only happens sometimes but when it happens it just hangs my server. Any idea of how can I prevent this?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make multiple watch requests for the same resource? Does this always happen with the same resource? Have you noticed this behaviour in any other resource? Have you tried [stopping notifications](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/push#stopping-notifications) for this particular resource and then recreate the channel? Could you share the code you used to create the channel, if any?

Comment: @Iamblichus: The channel are created  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/watch as per this reference. Yes, I have tried to stop this channel using postman API but after that still, I am getting push notification for 15-20 minutes. No, it happens with different resources as well but when it start it can't be stopped and all data are duplicates and if I haven't made any change on membership then also this notifications are generated. How this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this just for documentation purposes.

This behaviour has been reported in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153139813) (I guess the author of this question reported it). Anyone who is experiencing this can keep track of the issue by clicking the star on the top left of the referenced page.

#### Reference:

- [Google Admin SDK : Reports API Activities : Watch > Sends a tones of same notification](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153139813)